Intelegence documents processing using nodejs libraries
I am Working on a new project where I get orders via email as a PDF file. Depending on the company sending the order the layout may vary.
Each order usually contains the name, address, and description of the damage that needs to be repaired. All orders have a special number like an ID. However, it differs in how it is labeled. Some call it order ID, others call it order number, etc... with no prefixed pattern. The name and address layout also vary from company to company. Mostly it is the name of the customer followed by the address (next line below the name). Sometimes the address is 2 lines (street name & street number followed by city and ZIP code on the next line).
Now ChatGPT does an amazing job extracting the data. However, the data needs to be processed locally due to privacy protection and to save money since the company is new and does not have a lot of cash to spend.
Anyone can advise me on what technologies can be used in this scenario?
I am a web developer, and I have never done such a project. I rather stick with nodejs stuff since the project is already using node. However, if there is no other way I am open to other languages/technologies.

What do you mean by technologies?  Are you looking for software, libraries.  If the latter, what language?

@RohitGupta Yes, Node libraries. The documents are in German.
